# I can't find my error in my code. The aside Total Estimae isn't displaying

Tags: javascript

This code is for Chapter 2 of JavaScript by Sasha Vodnik and Dan Gosselin - Sixth Edition.

I cannot find out why my estimate does not show in the aside. I compared to the version my professor gave us and I cannot find the error causing the estimate not to show. Does anyone know what my error is?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <!--
  JavaScript 6th Edition
  Chapter 2
  Chapter case

  Fan Trick Fine Art Photography
  Estimate web page
  Author: 
  Date:   September 23, 2015

  Filename: estimate.htm
   -->
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography - Estimate</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 999px)href="fthand.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)"href="fantrick.css" />
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="ftie.css" />
  <![endif]-->
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mr+Bedfort' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
      <header>
     <h1>
            <img src="images/ftlogo.png" alt="Fan Trick Fine Art Photography" title="" />
         </h1>
      </header>

  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="currentpage"><a href="#">Estimate</a></li>
        <li><a href="digital.htm">Digital 101</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
     <h2>Estimate</h2>
     <p>Our experienced, professional photography team is available to capture memories of your wedding, celebration, or other special event.</p>
     <p>Choose the custom options that fit your needs:</p>
     <form id="estimateform">
        <fieldset>
           <legend><span>Photography</span></legend>
           <input type="number" min="0" max="4" id="photognum" value="1" />
           <label for="photognum">
              <p># of photographers (1&#8209;4)</p>
              <p>$100/hr</p>
           </label>

           <input type="number" min="2" id="photoghrs" value="2" />
           <label for="photoghrs">
              <p># of hours to photograph (minimum&nbsp;2)</p>
           </label>

           <input type="checkbox" id="membook" />
           <label for="membook">
              <p>Memory book</p>
              <p>$250</p>
           </label>

           <input type="checkbox" id="reprodrights" />
           <label for="reprodrights">
              <p>Reproduction rights for all photos</p>
              <p>$1250</p>
           </label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
           <legend><span>Travel</span></legend>
           <input type="number" id="distance" value="0" />
           <label for="distance">
              <p>Event distance from Austin, TX</p>
              <p>$1/mi per photographer</p>
           </label>
        </fieldset>
     </form>
  </article>
  <aside>
     <p>Total Estimate: <span id="estimate"></span></p>
  </aside>
  <footer>
     <p>Fan Trick Fine Art Photography &bull; Austin, Texas</p>
  </footer>
  </div>
  <script src="ft.js"></script> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

```js
/*    JavaScript 6th Edition
 *    Chapter 2
 *    Chapter case

 *    Fan Trick Fine Art Photography
 *    Variables and functions
 *    Author: 
 *    Date:   September 23, 2015

 *    Filename: ft.js
 */

// global variables

var photographerCost = 0;
var totalCost = 0;
var memoryBook = false;
var reproductionRights = false;

// calculates all costs based on staff and adds to total cost

function calcStaff() {
    var num = document.getElementById("photognum");
    var hrs = document.getElementById("photoghrs");
    var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
    totalCost -= photographerCost;
    photographerCost = num.value * 100 * hrs.value + distance.value * num.value;
    totalCost += photographerCost;
    document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}   
// adds/subtracts cost of memory book from total cost

function toggleMembook() {
    (document.getElementById("membook").checked === false) ? totalCost -= 250 : totalCost += 250;
    document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}

// adds/subtracts cost of reproduction rights from total cost

function toggleRights() {
    (document.getElementById("reprodrights").checked === false) ? totalCost -= 1250 : totalCost += 1250;
    document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}

// sets all form field values to defaults

function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("photogum").value = 1;
    document.getElementById("photoghrs").value = 2;
    document.getElementById("membook").checked = memoryBook;
    document.getElementById("reprodrights").checked = reproductionRights;
    document.getElementById("distance").value = 0;
    calcStaff();
    createEventListeners();
}

// creates event listeners

function createEventListeners() {
    document.getElementById("photognum").addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
    document.getElementById("photoghrs").addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
    document.getElementById("membook").addEventListener("change", toggleMembook, false);
    document.getElementById("reprodrights").addEventListener("change", toggleRights, false);
    document.getElementById("distance").addEventListener("change", calcStaff, false);
}

 // resets form when page is reloaded

 window.addEventListener("load", resetForm, false);
```

Comment: I'm assuming `ft.js` is your script and that that script block isn't just included at the end of your HTML file?

Comment: resetForm() never even fires.

Answer (score 1):

```
function resetForm() {
    document.getElementById("photogum").value = 1;
//                           ^^^^^^^^ doesn't exist should be
    document.getElementById("photognum").value = 1;
```

console log would've told you that

that's just from a cursory glance

Answer (score 1):

so I know it's five years later, and you probably don't care anymore, but for anyone else who is running into this... I found the solution. (re: JavaScript, by Sasha Vodnik and Don Gosselin, 6th Edition - Chapter 2, Tutorial Problem)

**The code as written in the book**... (if you follow the step-by-step instructions) it **doesn't call the createEventListeners() function**.

(Maybe it does? Maybe I missed it? Maybe I can't read. I'll look over it again but I'm pretty sure the only call to the createEventListeners function is in the resetForm() function.)

I added a function call at the bottom of the page, and now the estimate displaying works just fine.

```js
createEventListeners()
```

TL;DR -- ***make sure you call your functions*** - especially createEventListeners() :D